# failed to load Component.js: 404 - Not Found

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

My colleague has developed an extension project to *Approve Purchase Contract* application using local trial Web IDE. I imported his project using the licensed Web IDE from SAP gateway server. The folder structure looks like this:

[image: folder].

My `index.html` looks like this:

[image: index.html].

Whenever I run using `index.html` or `Component.js`, I'm getting below error. Kindly help.

> Uncaught Error: failed to load
>   'ui/s2p/mm/purcontract/approve/MM_PC_APVExtension/Component.js' from
>   ./Component.js: Error: failed to load
>   'ui/s2p/mm/purcontract/approve/Component.js' from
>   /sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/MM_PC_APV/Component.js: 404 - Not Found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says:
*ui/s2p/mm/purcontract/approve/MM_PC_APVExtension/Component.js* is found but it can not be loaded because a dependency is not found. That missing dependency is *ui/s2p/mm/purcontract/approve/Component.js* which should be available at */sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/MM_PC_APV/Component.js*.

Please follow the SAP Documentation [DOC-58342](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-58342) step 4.2 to be sure the "Approve Purchase Contract App" is installed and activated and the necessary roles are assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks schnoedel. I resolved the issue by recreating the extension project and copying the code changes from old project.